# Drop down menu almost works, but not perfecly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a login drop down menu but sometimes it slides 2 times.
i cant find the problem maby some of you guys know the issue.

here is my code:

Jquery:

```
$("div#drop_down").hide();

$("p.login_trigger").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#drop_down").slideDown(250); 
});

$("#drop_down").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).slideUp(250); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="login_area">
    <p class="login_trigger">Login
        <div id="drop_down">
            <form id="" name="" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="username" class="username" /><br />
                <input type="password" name="password" class="password" /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Login" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#login_area p.login_trigger {
display:block;
padding:6px;
background-color:#e2e2e2;
color:#4a4a4a;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
z-index:99;
```

}

```
div#login_area div#drop_down {
position:absolute;
right:20px;
top:40px;
background-color:#e2e2e2;
border:1px solid #e2e2e2;
padding:10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px 0px 4px 4px;
border-radius: 4px 0px 4px 4px;
z-index:9;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is alternative which tracks the state of the login div.   The object here is to change behavior based upon completed state transitions.   This is accomplished via:

1. Using addClass,hasClass and removeClass to identify the state of the div.
2. Using the callback functions of slideDown and slideUp to update the state.

With the state covered the mouseleave is conditional upon `hasClass("dropped")` being true.

```
$("p.login_trigger").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#drop_down").slideDown(250, function() { $(this).addClass( "dropped" ); } ); 
});

$("#drop_down").mouseleave(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("dropped"))
        $(this).slideUp(250, function() { $(this).removeClass("dropped") }); 
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RvJx/)

Answer (score 2):

Insert `.stop()` method before sliding:

```
$("div#drop_down").hide();

$("p.login_trigger").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#drop_down").stop().slideDown(250); 
});

$("#drop_down").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).stop().slideUp(250); 
});
```

Comment: Haha awsome, the answer is sometimes so simple. i was struggling for hours with this. I feel so stupid now :( Thanks alot !!

Comment: Good luck yo you :) hope you will help others in the future :)

Comment: you could also prevent propagation with `function(e){e.stopPropagation(); $("#drop_down").stop().slideDown(250);}`. This will wake sure no other event is fired

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

JS

```
$("div#drop_down").hide();

$("p.login_trigger").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#drop_down").slideDown(250); 
});

$("p.login_trigger").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#drop_down").slideUp(250); 
});
```

Make following change in css :

```
div#login_area div#drop_down {
    top:47px;    
}
```

[HERE IS JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yaF5f/)